# Vertical Text In Firefox

Tags: css

I want to have a vertical text (going from top to bottom instead of from left to right). I used:

```
.vertical {
    writing-mode: tb-rl;
}
```

But that doesn't work in Firefox. Is there any cross-browser compatible way to achieve vertical text?

Comment: Maybe this will help for the firefox case: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/721811-solution-display-text-rotated-90-vertically-firefox-css

Comment: You can do it in css only, take a look at my answer to [this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451617/how-to-create-vertical-text-using-only-css/1451643#1451643).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a MSIE proprietary CSS3 property. It will take a long time (maybe never) that the w3c will adopt it in the standard so that other browsers will follow. Best solution as far may be to use Flash. There are tools for that: [sIFR](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/) and [swfIR](http://www.swfir.com/). Alternatives are Javascript and/or images.

I however question the value of vertical text in usability context.

Comment: Little update: There's a new working draft of the W3C covering this at http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-writing-modes/.

Answer (score 1):

Put each line in its own div and insert a `<br>` element between each character.