# Is it possible to make text display vertically with css?

Tags: css

```
L
i
k
e

t
h
i
s
```

Can you answer by a demo?

For those of you don't know what kind of effect I need,see [here](http://51hired.com/test/t4.html)(this one only works in IE, which is basically what I want).

I don't need the text to rotate. Only vertical is necessary!

effect image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [51hired.com](http://51hired.com/tmpImg/effect.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Why do you need to achieve this effect?  Maybe there's a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: @codeinthehole ,show me the better way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create vertical text using only CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451617/how-to-create-vertical-text-using-only-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create vertical text using only CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451617/how-to-create-vertical-text-using-only-css)

Answer (score 5):

A solution for FireFox (and possibly other browsers) here:
http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/721811-solution-display-text-rotated-90-vertically-firefox-css

An IE-specific solution here:
http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/vertical-text.shtml

Comment: That's too complicated,is an easier one available?

Comment: Well, you could do it the way you did it in your question.

Comment: If the question was to not just draw a text vertically but also have the letters rotated that way, then this would be the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to set a fixed, small width for the container. If you print your text interleaving spaces, then they should show one below the other.

Comment: I would say that is a simple yet effective solution. +1

Comment: Ohh, I see. It'd be great if you updated your question with a screenshot of the desired effect (instead of a link), for those who don't want to use IE, or just don't have it!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but a series of line breaks (`<br>` elements) should do the trick.

Comment: Maybe jquery / js could be used to inject a <br/> after each letter?

Answer (score 0):

This is simplest way by adding space between letters and width 1px

css:

```
p{width:1px;}
```

HTML

```
<p>L i k e t h i s</p>
```

Now output will come as you like

```
L
i
k
e

t
h
i
s
```

Answer (score -1):

The fastest route to the finish line will be to craft an image with the text laid out the way you want. Be sure to add an `alt` attribute to its `img` element wherever used, so search engines can index it properly.

By the way, that's an issue with the markup-based solutions: search engines may not match words in the label if their letters are separated by tags.

Comment: That certainly is the trivial solution. Not elegant, not nice, not flexible but does the job.