# How can i show text in vertical

Tags: css

Is it possible to show text vertically with css e.g. i want the text to be shown like

```
H
E
L
L
O
```

i have tried some examples on the web but they didn't worked, please help.

Regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create vertical text using only CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451617/how-to-create-vertical-text-using-only-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet for cross-browser compatability is to make a narrow container which forces the word to break at each letter.

Have a look at this demo:

- http://sarfraznawaz2005.kodingen.com/demos/css/vertical_text2.html

It works nicely and the code is straightforward and commented.  Specifically look at this bit:

```
/* vartical text css starts */
.vertical{
    width:1em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
/* vartical text css ends */
```